# Does Scale Up of Azure App Service Plan (Linux) cause downtime?

Tags: azure-app-service-plans

I would need more performance for Azure Functions.

Does scale up from P1v2 to P2v2 cause downtime to services?
How long the downtime would be if any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, any scale up/down cause down time as it changes underline hardware and perform deployment on new hardware (compute).

**How long it cause downtime ?**
It completely depends on application hosted on that plan and how much time application start up takes and dependencies during start up. So its completely depends on the application hosted on that plan.